# Python Help: How to find if 3 or 4 strings are the same in a list of 7 strings?

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, compare

I am creating a game of rummy in which I enter in 7 cards.
A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K is the number of the card.
And S, H, C, D are the suits (spades, hearts, clubs, diamonds)
Ex. 8H is hearts of 8

Code:

```
card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7 = input('1. ').split(', ')

c1p1, c1p2 = card1[:-1], card1[1:]

c2p1, c2p2 = card2[:-1], card2[1:]

c3p1, c3p2 = card3[:-1], card3[1:]

c4p1, c4p2 = card4[:-1], card4[1:]

c5p1, c5p2 = card5[:-1], card5[1:]

c6p1, c6p2 = card6[:-1], card6[1:]

c7p1, c7p2 = card7[:-1], card7[1:]
```

Im splitting the entry of the user from the card number and suit.
The objective of this program is to find if they are 3 to 4 cards that have the same number but I dont know how to compare all 7 numbers to find if 3-4 of them are equal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure it's the best way, but one option would be to recursively reduce over the list, with a lambda checking equality to the first string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a dictionary to count the times a number appears, try the following piece of code:

```
def method():
    cards_string = "8H,3S,4H,7D,5C,JH,AS"
    cards = cards_string.split(',')
    card_numbers_count = {'A':0, '2':0, '3':0, '4':0, '5':0, '6':0, '7':0, '8':0, '9':0, '10':0, 'J':0, 'Q':0, 'K':0}

    for card in cards:
        card_number = card[:-1]
        card_numbers_count[card_number] += 1

    print card_numbers_count


if __name__ == "__main__":
    method()
```

Comment: @user2224963 it's a good practice to accept the answer, that way it does not stay unanswered.

Comment: im new to stackoverflow so im not quite sure how to do that :\

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like
 list.count(listElement)

```
for item in list:
    c= list.count(item)
    if c>3:
        print "card %s is more than 3 times"%item
```